# How to debug javascript that is crashing Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

As a bit of fun I've been attempting to implement a Tetris clone in Javascript using the Canvas. I've got it to the point where it *kind of* works in the latest versions of Chrome and IE. however on my macbook it crashes Safari 8.0.3. It plays for about 4 seconds and the spinner appears as soon as I try to give any sort of input. I've tried using the profiler but that crashes too.

Is there anything else I can try to debug this issue short of removing code until it works?

In case it's of any help the site is here http://jsetris.gavindraper.com

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: I'm looking for general javascript crash debug ideas. I can't really post code as I don't know what part of the game loop is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the console in Chrome I do see a warning:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
detrimental effects to the end user's experience
```

I don't know if this could help to figure out if there is an issue with your code that could be making Safari unhappy?